# htaccess for swf file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Does htaccess works with swf file that accepts variables?

I have this swf url...

`http://subdom.domain.tld/subfolder/live.swf?stream=rtmp://stream.domain.com/application&provider=rtmp&file=streamname&autostart=true`

I want it to be rewrite as
`http://subdom.domain.tld/subfolder/assignedname/`

So far this is what I written on .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^kwt/?$ live.swf?stream=rtmp://stream.domain.com/application&provider=rtmp&file=streamname&autostart=true [NC,L]
```

It does seem to rewrite to the swf file because the swf is showing but for some reason the variable is not recognized. It does not auto play even the auto play variable is set to true in the RewriteRule.

Is there something wrong with my code or it can't be done in swf file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, because the Flash player looks at the 'displayed' URL for variables in the query string, and a rewritten, 'clean' URL doesn't have those.

Comment: No problem. If you think that this answer is appropriate, feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left if you wish. Welcome to Stack Overflow!